# ImportError: No module named ce_libs.utilities.Logger

Tags: linux, python

- I have a directory called `ce_libs`.  Inside this I have a `utilities` directory and inside that I have a `logger.py` module containing a `logger` class.
- I am executing a test: `/mypath/test.py`
- `test.py` has an `import` statement; i.e., `from ce_libs.utilities.Logger import logger`

I am getting the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named ce_libs.utilities.Logger
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Linux is case-sensitive: `foo`, `Foo`, and `FOO` are different.  If your module is called `logger.py`, you should probably import from `ce_libs.utilities.logger` and not `ce_libs.utilities.Logger`.